# Rendering NV12/YUV image in DirectX 12

Tags: yuv, directx-12

Having a bit of trouble mapping the texture data correctly in order to read Chrominance and Luminance in the shader. The Luminance is rendering fine, but the Chrominance is all zeros... I know I need to create two SRVs and map the Y to 1 channel, UV to 2. I'm assuming there's something really obvious I'm missing but the docs on the Microsoft website are very unhelpful.

Data is 1920 * 1080, meaning the size per frame is 1920 * 1080 * 1.5. I know I should get 3 bytes per pixel, giving me a larger pitch, but when I add this to the code I get an illegal write exception.

The code is otherwise working, just my inability to map the texture properly. I'd really appreciate any help.

Code below:

Creating my PSO:

```
CD3DX12_DESCRIPTOR_RANGE descRanges[2];
descRanges[(uint32_t)DescriptorTableIndex::Texture].Init(D3D12_DESCRIPTOR_RANGE_TYPE_SRV, 2, 0, 0); // t0, t1
descRanges[(uint32_t)DescriptorTableIndex::Sampler].Init(D3D12_DESCRIPTOR_RANGE_TYPE_SAMPLER, 1, 0); // s0

CD3DX12_ROOT_PARAMETER rootParams[2];
rootParams[(uint32_t)DescriptorTableIndex::Texture].InitAsDescriptorTable(1, &descRanges[(uint32_t)DescriptorTableIndex::Texture], D3D12_SHADER_VISIBILITY_PIXEL);
rootParams[(uint32_t)DescriptorTableIndex::Sampler].InitAsDescriptorTable(1, &descRanges[(uint32_t)DescriptorTableIndex::Sampler], D3D12_SHADER_VISIBILITY_PIXEL);
CD3DX12_ROOT_SIGNATURE_DESC rootSignatureLayout(ARRAYSIZE(rootParams), rootParams, 0, 0,
    D3D12_ROOT_SIGNATURE_FLAG_ALLOW_INPUT_ASSEMBLER_INPUT_LAYOUT |
    D3D12_ROOT_SIGNATURE_FLAG_DENY_HULL_SHADER_ROOT_ACCESS |
    D3D12_ROOT_SIGNATURE_FLAG_DENY_DOMAIN_SHADER_ROOT_ACCESS |
    D3D12_ROOT_SIGNATURE_FLAG_DENY_GEOMETRY_SHADER_ROOT_ACCESS);

ComPtr<ID3DBlob> serializedRootSignature;
DxUtil::ThrowIfFailed(D3D12SerializeRootSignature(&rootSignatureLayout, D3D_ROOT_SIGNATURE_VERSION_1, &serializedRootSignature, nullptr));

ComPtr<ID3D12RootSignature> pNv12RootSignature = nullptr;
DxUtil::ThrowIfFailed(mDevice->CreateRootSignature(
    1,
    serializedRootSignature->GetBufferPointer(),
    serializedRootSignature->GetBufferSize(),
    IID_PPV_ARGS(&pNv12RootSignature)));

ComPtr<ID3DBlob> serializedRootSignature;
DxUtil::ThrowIfFailed(D3D12SerializeRootSignature(&rootSignatureLayout, D3D_ROOT_SIGNATURE_VERSION_1, &serializedRootSignature, nullptr));

ComPtr<ID3D12RootSignature> pNv12RootSignature = nullptr;
DxUtil::ThrowIfFailed(mDevice->CreateRootSignature(
    1,
    serializedRootSignature->GetBufferPointer(),
    serializedRootSignature->GetBufferSize(),
    IID_PPV_ARGS(&pNv12RootSignature)));

// Define the vertex input layout.
D3D12_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC inputElementDescription[] =
{
    { "POSITION", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT, 0, 0,                            D3D12_INPUT_CLASSIFICATION_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0 },
    { "TEXCOORD", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32_FLOAT,    0, D3D12_APPEND_ALIGNED_ELEMENT, D3D12_INPUT_CLASSIFICATION_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0 },

    // Instance data
    { "ID",             0,  DXGI_FORMAT_R32_UINT,           1,  0,                              D3D12_INPUT_CLASSIFICATION_PER_INSTANCE_DATA,   1},
    { "MATRIX",         0,  DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT, 1,  D3D12_APPEND_ALIGNED_ELEMENT,   D3D12_INPUT_CLASSIFICATION_PER_INSTANCE_DATA,   1},
    { "MATRIX",         1,  DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT, 1,  D3D12_APPEND_ALIGNED_ELEMENT,   D3D12_INPUT_CLASSIFICATION_PER_INSTANCE_DATA,   1},
    { "MATRIX",         2,  DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT, 1,  D3D12_APPEND_ALIGNED_ELEMENT,   D3D12_INPUT_CLASSIFICATION_PER_INSTANCE_DATA,   1},
    { "MATRIX",         3,  DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT, 1,  D3D12_APPEND_ALIGNED_ELEMENT,   D3D12_INPUT_CLASSIFICATION_PER_INSTANCE_DATA,   1}
};

// Describe and create the graphics pipeline state object (PSO).
D3D12_GRAPHICS_PIPELINE_STATE_DESC psoDesc = {};
psoDesc.InputLayout = { inputElementDescription, _countof(inputElementDescription) };
psoDesc.pRootSignature = pNv12RootSignature.Get();
psoDesc.VS = CD3DX12_SHADER_BYTECODE(g_nv12Vs, sizeof(g_nv12Vs));
psoDesc.PS = CD3DX12_SHADER_BYTECODE(g_nv12Ps, sizeof(g_nv12Ps));
psoDesc.RasterizerState = CD3DX12_RASTERIZER_DESC(D3D12_DEFAULT);
psoDesc.BlendState = blendDesc;
psoDesc.DepthStencilState.DepthEnable = FALSE;
psoDesc.DepthStencilState.StencilEnable = FALSE;
psoDesc.SampleMask = UINT_MAX;
psoDesc.PrimitiveTopologyType = D3D12_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TYPE_TRIANGLE;
psoDesc.NumRenderTargets = 1;
psoDesc.RTVFormats[0] = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
psoDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 2;
DxUtil::ThrowIfFailed(mDevice->CreateGraphicsPipelineState(&psoDesc, IID_PPV_ARGS(&pPipelineState)));

StateSignaturePair stateSignaturePair(pPipelineState, pNv12RootSignature);
mPipelineStateObjects.insert(std::pair<PipelineState, StateSignaturePair>(PipelineState::NV12, stateSignaturePair));
```

Create my SRVs:

```
D3D12_SHADER_RESOURCE_VIEW_DESC luminanceDesc = {};
luminanceDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8_UNORM;
luminanceDesc.ViewDimension = D3D12_SRV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D;
luminanceDesc.Texture2D.MipLevels = 1;
luminanceDesc.Shader4ComponentMapping = D3D12_DEFAULT_SHADER_4_COMPONENT_MAPPING;

mDevice->CreateShaderResourceView(layerCache->mTexture->getTexture(), &luminanceDesc, layerCache->mSrvHeap->GetCpuHandle(NV12SrvIndex::Y));

D3D12_SHADER_RESOURCE_VIEW_DESC chrominaceDesc = {};
chrominaceDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8_UNORM;
chrominaceDesc.ViewDimension = D3D12_SRV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D;
chrominaceDesc.Texture2D.MipLevels = 1;
chrominaceDesc.Shader4ComponentMapping = D3D12_DEFAULT_SHADER_4_COMPONENT_MAPPING;
chrominaceDesc.Texture2D.PlaneSlice = 1;

mDevice->CreateShaderResourceView(layerCache->mTexture->getTexture(), &chrominaceDesc, layerCache->mSrvHeap->GetCpuHandle(NV12SrvIndex::UV));
```

Texture:

```
mTextureDescription.Width = 1920;
mTextureDescription.Height = 1080;
mTextureDescription.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_NV12;
mTextureDescription.Flags = D3D12_RESOURCE_FLAG_NONE;
mTextureDescription.Dimension = D3D12_RESOURCE_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D;
mTextureDescription.MipLevels = 1;
mTextureDescription.DepthOrArraySize = 1;
mTextureDescription.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
mTextureDescription.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;

mTextureData.pData = pData;

// Row pitch is how wide our line is in bytes.
mTextureData.RowPitch = mTextureDescription.Width; // I'm pretty sure this isn't right...
mTextureData.SlicePitch = mTextureData.RowPitch * mTextureDescription.Height;
```

Comment: What is the output of the display, by rendering you mean in RGBA/BGRA output?

Comment: Yes! That's the one. I know how to transform it within the shader, but creating the correct Srv and descriptor for the shader is proving difficult. I know I could just split the raw data up and then provide two samplers, two textures etc but there is a more succint way of doing it.

Comment: I have managed to do it with the help of VideoProcessorBlt which I think is a better solution, however you can also check my YUV to RGBA that might help you. Reference code MediaDecoder.cs -> ProcessVideo and MediaRenderer.cs -> PresentNV12P010 https://github.com/SuRGeoNix/Flyleaf/tree/master/Flyleaf

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. Sadly I don't think this helps me, because I am sure that there are problems in my DX12 texture and maybe the SRV too. Setting those up properly will be the solution to getting the DX to treat is as a single texture. But I've implemented it as described above which isn't the nicest way but it works.